# How to use the console code in the .NET in visual studio

Tags: c#

I have tested my code in the console and everything was right, but when I am trying to use the same code in my GUI (.NET) and getting errors like below!

.NET:

No Error!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Console" here. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @Llama sorry. I mean console application in visual studio

Comment: Uh, well, a C# Console Application is also built on .NET. So there's no difference between ".NET" and "Console" from that point of view.

Comment: @Llama I am beginner programmer. I am getting this error when I want to create a GUI with the same code!

Comment: I also doubt it results in the actual list you are expecting.

Comment: I am getting an error "Can not convert from string to char", but the same code work in Console ApplicatioN!

Comment: Which line of code produces this error? Are both projects targetting the same framework and version (e.g. both .NET Framework 4.7, or both .NET 5, or both .NET Core 3.1, etc.)?

Comment: @Llama var FileNames_List_Jetzt_Dateien = FileNames_Jetzt_Dateien.Split(",").ToList();  In this line

Comment: Actually, it's the line above:

Comment: `string.Join` results in a `string`. If you call `.Select()` on it, the parameter is of type `char` (interpreting string as IEnumerable<char>). `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` expects a `string`, though.

Comment: The fact that the IDE points to the following line is due to late execution. (Because you are not doing a `ToList()` or àsEnumerable` or the like)

Comment: Actually, this is wasted time. I guess, you want to strip all filenames in the list from their ".html" extension, do you? In that case, you don't need to join and split _at all_.

Comment: @Fildor yes I am trying to do that

Comment: Exactly. Then joining them into one string doesn't make sense. Select on the enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you created your GUI project using .NET Framework which, even in [.NET Framework 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8), doesn't have a `Split` overload that accepts a single `string` by itself. There is a method that takes an array of `string`, and `StringSplitOptions`

In .NET Framework, you would write something like:

```
string[] entries = myString.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

In contrast, .NET Core since 2.0 (and .NET 5) has a [`Split` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_) that accepts a single `string` as the separator, and has a default value for `StringSplitOptions`. This means that code like this is valid:

```
string[] entries = myString.Split(",");
```

I therefore believe your console application must be being built against .NET Core 2.0+ or .NET 5, whereas your GUI application is being built against the .NET Framework.

To check the target framework of your project, simply right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Properties".

Comment: While that's a good explanaition of the behavior perceived, this is a x-y-Question. OP is simply not doing what he thinks he's doing.

Comment: @Fildor I agree that's possibly true. I expect OP will find that out in due course and (potentially) ask a new question about that problem.

Comment: Good catch on that split, by the way!

Comment: @Fildor I just suddenly remembered that it used to get to me that I had to create an array to split by string, but could split by a single char without creating an array, so I went and checked the docs to be sure. :)